# home-built router - slow throughput

Tags: linux, networking

I am having slow performance with my home-built router.  Compared to a stock Verizon (actiontec) router, it gets about 60 Mpbs down and 30 Mpbs up whereas I get about 15 Mbps and 20 Mbps up.  I switched out my home-built router (an old laptop computer) for a desktop and the performance dropped to 2 Mbps down and 10 Mpbs up all the time whereas the laptop seemed to be consistently faster with the occasional slow-down.

Now, I am doing traffic shaping; however, that shouldn't be the dominant problem.  With the laptop, I still randomly did get 2 Mbps down randomly so I'm not sure if it is hardware or software (configuration).  They share the same hardware (when testing, I used a USB ethernet adapter since both devices come with 1 onboard NIC).  It *could* be a faulty NIC (the USB ethernet adapter), but it could more likely be configuration.

When capturing traffic with wireshark/tshark, I see a bunch of duplicate ACKs and TCP retransmissions.  That could indicate bad wiring, but if I'm using that same cable for outbound traffic, that likely is not the issue.  I also later measured bandwidth on the cable and found it to be 97.2 Mbps (one NIC is only 10/100).  It could be a faulty NIC (the USB ethernet adapter), but why would I still get more performance on the laptop with it?

Comment: What's the CPU usage on this laptop like when you're using the internet ? and what's it like when downloading large files ?

Comment: I am thinking the network card is bad.  I will have to check this more thoroughly though as the other NIC works fine, but it just appears to be a problem when connected through this NIC.  CPU usage is very minimal, idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NIC was actually bad.  I replaced it and am seeing the same throughput as a stock router if not about 10% better (time will tell).

Correction, it appears the memory was bad and the first way it manifested itself was the NIC was not functioning properly.  After I replaced the NIC with another one, I had other issues, so that led me to run some other tests and find that the memory modules were the problem.

Comment: The router has been performing much better than a stock router after having measured performance over the duration.  It is important to monitor performance over time so you can suspect a hardware / configuration issue, unfortunately, this one didn't manifest itself other than slow throughput.